# Display "imshow" images in a GUI using GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a piece of code that is 300 lines long. There is 3 different instances of imshow throughout the code that displays figures as the code is run.. 
The GUI I am creating will be very simple. Currently I have a push button that initiates the m file. 
I am trying to get the images to be displayed within the GUI that I am creating and not in separate Figure windows. 
I have being looking at tutorials online but cant get a quick fix for my problem, they all get a bit convoluted and I cant figure out what exactly to do.

I have 3 axis inserted onto the GUI, In the "view callbacks" for each axis I can createfcn, deletefcn and buttonDownFcn. When I createFcn it gives me a hint to "place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1" in the auto generated code.

I have tried to do this but I am not able to find the correct place to write the code.

Can somebody tell me if I am going in the correct direction or if I have it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How about `img = imread('peppers.jpg'); image(img, 'Parent', handles.axes1);` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is just giving me a error when i insert that:
"Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Undefined variable "handles" or function "handles.axes4".

Error in FullProgram (line 37)
imshow(Image); image(Image, 'Parent', handles.axes4)
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback"

Answer (score 2):

In order to display these images, you need to declare the parent in imshow.  The parent is what you want to act as the canvas for your image, and in your case will be an `axes`.

I created a very simple gui with three axes and a push button.  MATLAB named my axes `axes1`, `axes2` and `axes3`.  Guide saves the handles to these axes so that you can interact with them throughout your gui code.  For example, you mentioned the opening function... here is mine with a call to imshow (the only lines I added were the last three ones):

```
% --- Executes just before myGUI is made visible.
function myGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% Choose default command line output for myGUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes myGUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);
imshow('myImage1.png', 'Parent', handles.axes1)
imshow('myImage2.png', 'Parent', handles.axes2)
imshow('myImage3.png', 'Parent', handles.axes3)
```

Notice that I can grab the handles of my axes and then declare them to be the parents for the results of my `imshow` call.

If you're not sure what the names of your handles are, you can check in the GUI editor by right clicking, looking at the property inspector, and the `tag` property.

If you want to perform a similar operation for when you click on your pushbutton, right click on the button in the editor, and click on View Callbacks -> Callback, and you can add your `imshow` code there.

Good luck.

Comment: Thats a great explanation, I have it all set. It is giving me a error because my output from imshow is imshow(Image); How can I have the GUI look for "Image" instead of something like 'myImage1.png' as you detailed above

Comment: As a user, how is the Image variable created?

Comment: It is the output of a imread('sampleImage.jpg');   After filtering and transform have being performed.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to share the data from your transform between different callbacks.  There are a bunch of ways to do this.  This video might help explain them: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/11/23/passing-data-between-guide-callbacks-without-globals-in-matlab/

Comment: If you just need something that works though, you could save the transformed image to a mat file using `save('myFile.mat', Image)` and then load it again when you need it `load('myFile.mat')`.  Note that this is not good programming practice and should be eventually replaced with a solution recommended by the MathWorks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want your images to appear in the axes instead of a figure. Try setting the focus to the axes itself before showing the image.

```
    axes(1);%you may need to change the one to your axes handle. 
    imagesc(imageToBeDisplayed);

    axes(2);
    imagesc(secondImage);

    axes(3);
    imagesc(thirdImage);
```

This way before you call imagesc you make sure your program knows where to send the image. Otherwise it may just create a figure.